# Why does a lazy-static value claim to not implement a trait that it clearly implements?

Tags: rust, reqwest

With the following code (an attempt to make an HTTP request using the `reqwest` crate), the compiler says that my value `SID_URI` does not implement the trait `PolyfillTryInto`. What's going on here? [`reqwest::Url` clearly implements the private trait `reqwest::into_url::PolyfillTryInto`.](https://docs.rs/reqwest/0.8.1/src/reqwest/into_url.rs.html#18)

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate lazy_static;
extern crate reqwest;

static R_EMAIL: &str = "example@example.com";
static R_PASS: &str = "password";
static API_PUBKEY: &str = "99754106633f94d350db34d548d6091a";
static API_URI: &str = "https://example.com";
static AUTH_PATH: &str = "/api/v1";

lazy_static! {
    static ref SID_URI: reqwest::Url = reqwest::Url::parse(&(API_URI.to_owned() + AUTH_PATH)).unwrap();
}

fn get_sid() -> Result<reqwest::Response, reqwest::Error> {
    let client = reqwest::Client::new();
    let params = [("ID", R_EMAIL), ("PW", R_PASS), ("KY", API_PUBKEY)];
    let q = client.post(SID_URI).form(&params).send()?;
    Ok(q)
}

fn main() {
    assert!(get_sid().is_ok());
}
```

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `SID_URI: reqwest::into_url::PolyfillTryInto` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:19:20
   |
19 |     let q = client.post(SID_URI).form(&params).send()?;
   |                    ^^^^ the trait `reqwest::into_url::PolyfillTryInto` is not implemented for `SID_URI`
   |
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `reqwest::IntoUrl` for `SID_URI`
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The compiler isn't lying to you, you are just skipping over a relevant detail of the error message. Here's a self-contained example:

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate lazy_static;

struct Example;
trait ExampleTrait {}
impl ExampleTrait for Example {}

lazy_static! {
    static ref EXAMPLE: Example = Example;
}

fn must_have_trait<T>(_: T)
where
    T: ExampleTrait,
{
}

fn main() {
    must_have_trait(EXAMPLE);
    must_have_trait(42i32);
}
```

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `EXAMPLE: ExampleTrait` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:19:5
   |
19 |     must_have_trait(EXAMPLE);
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `ExampleTrait` is not implemented for `EXAMPLE`
   |
   = note: required by `must_have_trait`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `i32: ExampleTrait` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:20:9
   |
20 |         must_have_trait(42i32);
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `ExampleTrait` is not implemented for `i32`
   |
   = note: required by `must_have_trait`
```

Compare the two error messages:

```
the trait bound `EXAMPLE: ExampleTrait` is not satisfied
the trait bound `i32: ExampleTrait` is not satisfied
```

The second error message doesn't say that `42` does not implement `ExampleTrait`, it says that **`i32`** lacks the implementation. This error message shows the *type* that fails, not the name of the value! That means that `EXAMPLE` in the same context is referring to a type.

Lazy-static works by [creating one-off types](https://docs.rs/lazy_static/1.0.0/lazy_static/#semantics) that wrap your value and provide thread-safe single initialization guarantees:

> For a given `static ref NAME: TYPE = EXPR;`, the macro generates a unique type that implements `Deref<TYPE>` and stores it in a static with name `NAME`.

This wrapper type does not implement your trait, only the wrapped type does. You will need to invoke `Deref` and then probably re-reference it to get to a `&Url`, assuming that a reference to a `Url` implements your trait:

```
must_have_trait(&*EXAMPLE);
```

Additionally, using the bare static variable would attempt to move it out of the static location (which would be a Very Bad Thing), so you always need to use it by reference.

Comment: "This error message shows the type that fails, not the name of the value!" Very interesting. I think that the compiler could be improved to blame the type -- I really didn't understand why it was blaming the _value_, as if it were a type...thanks :)