# Define a static boolean in Rust from std::env::consts::OS=="windows"

Tags: rust, static, boolean, global, lazy-static

I'd like to create a global static boolean value called `IS_WINDOWS` in a Rust file:

```rust
lazy_static! {
    pub static ref IS_WINDOWS: bool = std::env::consts::OS=="windows";
}
```

However, when I do this, anything that references the `IS_WINDOWS` value from elsewhere doesn't see it as a `bool`, they instead see it as a custom `IS_WINDOWS` struct, i.e. trying to do:

```rust
if crate::globals::IS_WINDOWS {
}
```

...results in error:

```
mismatched types
expected `bool`, found struct `globals::IS_WINDOWS`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out, all I needed to do is use `*` to dereference the static variable:

```rust
if *crate::globals::IS_WINDOWS {
}
```

Comment: I'll go ahead and link [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48114390/why-does-a-lazy-static-value-claim-to-not-implement-a-trait-that-it-clearly-impl) explaining that lazy_static uses unique wrapper types for each variable, which is why the dereference is necessary.