# How do I avoid "cannot move out of static item" when using a lazy_static variable?

Tags: rust

I want to initialize a variable globally, so I used a package called `lazy_static`.

```rs
lazy_static::lazy_static! {
    static ref STRING: String = String::from("Hello, World");
}

fn main() {
    STRING;
}
```

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of static item `STRING`
 --> src/main.rs:6:5
  |
6 |     STRING;
  |     ^^^^^^ move occurs because `STRING` has type `STRING`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

I don't want to implement the `Copy` trait, I want to use same reference all over the application, like a `'static` lifetime.

Comment: Aside: do you really want a `String` here?  Perhaps `static STRING: &'static str = "Hello, world";` (no need for `lazy_static`) will suffice?  Indeed, in that case, it could even be `const`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't try to use the variable by value, use it by reference.

```
fn main() {
    &STRING;
}
```

See also:

- [How do I create a global, mutable singleton?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27791532/155423)
- [Why does a lazy-static value claim to not implement a trait that it clearly implements?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48114390/155423)